# Open an executable from combobox on button click issue

Tags: c#

I am fairly new to C# and am trying to open an executable file from a combobox with a button click. Could anyone give me some assistance or examples if possible? It would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you provide any code?

Comment: Have a look at the Process object https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.start(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Can you please show us the code so that people here can stop guessing for answers ?

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for is System.Diagnostics.Process.  Here's the one-liner:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("SomeProgram.exe");
```

... or ...

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("SomeProgram.exe", "arg1 arg2 arg3 etc");
```

... but you can get more intricate stuff, like setting window style, reading/routing standard out or standard error, etc.

```
// example of setting the window style via ProcessStartInfo
ProcessStartInfo myStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("SomeProgram.exe");
myStartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Maximized;
Process.Start(myStartInfo);
```